# Subset/select from a DFM using a dictionary in quanteda

Tags: r, text-mining, quanteda

I have a corpus of texts from various countries. I am trying to see how often a specific term appears in the texts for each country. To do so, I am following the example here: https://quanteda.io/articles/pkgdown/examples/plotting.html#frequency-plots

```
freq_grouped <- textstat_frequency(dfm(full_corpus), 
                                   groups = "Country")

freq_const <- subset(freq_grouped, freq_grouped$feature %in% "constitution")
```

This works fine, except that this only captures the exact term ("constitution"). I'd like to be able to capture variations of the term (e.g. "charter of rights and freedoms") use globs (e.g. "`*constitution*`"), and count the results under the same category. I tried using a dictionary for this, but I get zero results.

```
dict <- dictionary(list(constitution = c('*constitution*', 'charter of rights and freedoms', 
                                         'canadian charter', 'constituição*', '*constitucion*')))

freq_const <- subset(freq_grouped, freq_grouped$feature %in% dict)

freq_const
    [1] feature   frequency rank      docfreq   group    
    <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

How can I go about achieving this?

Comment: Try subsetting your `freq_grouped` object using `grepl()` for your pattern match, or the **stringi** alternative to `grepl()`. You can convert a glob into a regex using `glob2rx()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic answer is that you cannot subset a dfm using a dictionary or any other sort of pattern match, because `dfm_subset()` requires a logical value for its subset match that matches 1:1 with *documents*.  A dictionary would match features, not documents.

If you wanted to match *features* while not selecting documents, however -- which I think is what you intended -- then you can use `dfm_select()`, and a **quanteda** dictionary is a valid input for the `pattern` argument of that command.  With the `valuetype = "glob"` argument, furthermore, you can specify that your pattern match is a glob rather than a regex.

```
library("quanteda")

subdfm <- dfm(data_corpus_inaugural) %>%
    dfm_select(pattern = dict, valuetype = "glob")

head(subdfm)
## Document-feature matrix of: 6 documents, 5 features (66.7% sparse).
## 6 x 5 sparse Matrix of class "dfm"
##                  features
## docs              constitutional constitution constitutions constitutionally unconstitutional
##   1789-Washington              1            1             0                0                0
##   1793-Washington              1            1             0                0                0
##   1797-Adams                   0            8             1                0                0
##   1801-Jefferson               1            2             0                0                0
##   1805-Jefferson               0            6             0                0                0
##   1809-Madison                 0            1             0                0                0

textstat_frequency(subdfm)
##            feature frequency rank docfreq group
## 1     constitution       206    1      37   all
## 2   constitutional        53    2      24   all
## 3    constitutions         4    3       3   all
## 4 constitutionally         4    4       3   all
## 5 unconstitutional         3    5       3   all
```

If you have docvars for the corpus from which you create the dfm, you can also feed these to the `textstat_frequency()` call - they will be attached to dfm.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to address, this Ken. This addresses my question.

Comment: Somewhat related to the above, am I correct that the relative frequency plot you use in the examples page is actually calculating the weight per the total number of words in all of the presidents' speeches after 1949 rather than per president? If so, would it not make more sense to calculate these by president? Some presidents will have given shorter speeches than others, so a mention of the term of interest in one of those speeches would have more weight. Am I misinterpreting something?

Comment: For something in the documentation example, may I suggest that you file an issue at https://github.com/quanteda/quanteda/issues referring to the specific page, and tag the issue as "Question".